# Group by and aggregate a dictionary with multiple keys in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have an object of a class dict with three keys as follows:

```
d={(1, 'B', 0):1.0,(0, 'A', 1): 3.0,(1, 'A', 1): 0.0, (2, 'A', 0): 0.0, (0, 'B', 0): 2.0}
```

I am wondering if there is an efficient way to group by this dict by the the 2nd and 3rd elements of the key and sum the values. Something like this:

```
d_grouped = {('B', 0):3.0,('A', 1): 4.0,('A', 0): 0.0}
```

Comment: you have duplicate keys by the way that overwrite each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a defaultdict and iterate over d.items():

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = {(1, 'B', 0): 1.0,
     (0, 'A', 1): 3.0,
     (1, 'A', 1): 0.0,
     (0, 'A', 1): 1.0,
     (2, 'A', 0): 0.0,
     (0, 'B', 0): 2.0
     }

grouped = defaultdict(float)
for key, value in d.items():
    grouped[key[1], key[2]] += value

print(grouped)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'float'>, {('B', 0): 3.0, ('A', 1): 1.0, ('A', 0): 0.0})
```

Note: the input dict `d` has duplicate key `(0, 'A', 1)`

Answer (score 1):

```
def reduce_d(d):
    new_d = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        try:
            k_new = (k[1:])
            new_d[k_new] += v
        except KeyError:
            new_d[k_new] = v
    return new_d
```

output:

```
{('B', 0): 3.0, ('A', 1): 1.0, ('A', 0): 0.0}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d_grouped = {}
for (_,x,y), v in d.items():
    if (x,y) in d_grouped:
        d_grouped[(x,y)] += v
    else:
        d_grouped[(x,y)] = v
```